# FILE после открытия получает указатель 0x1

Tags: c, файлы, указатели

В main методе только вызов этой функции: `add_entry("123.txt", "123", "some text");`
После запуска создается файл и на строке fputs вылетает SIGSEGV.
Через дебагер запускаю и узнаю, что у `f` указатель `0x1` после открытия файла.

```
void add_entry(char* file, char* id, char* entry)
{
    FILE* f;
    if(f = fopen(file, "w+")!=NULL)
    {
        char* entry1 = calloc(strlen(entry)+strlen(id)+3, sizeof(char));
        sprintf(entry1, "%s|%s\n", id, entry);
        fputs(entry1, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну так

```
f = fopen(file, "w+")!=NULL
```

рассматривается компилятором как

```
f = (fopen(file, "w+")!=NULL)
```

так что все верно...

Пишите вот так:

```
(f = fopen(file, "w+"))!=NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я сам только что понял это.